# Custom ORDER BY clause by values in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I am trying to use custom sorting in Doctrine 2 (using MySQL). Code looks somehow like this:

```
$queryBuilder->orderBy("i.type = 5, i.type = 3, i.type = 7");
```

The error I get is this one: `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 72: Error: Expected end of string, got '='`.

I have found out that this is not possible because of compatibility with other database systems. So my questions is: How can do this in other way, directly in the query (if possible)?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Well, at the end, I haven't solution I wanted, but I had to do something else. At the end, the result was the desired one.

I selected the data normally and than by going throught the array and using array sort finished the job.

Answer (score -1):

OK, so I don't know anything about doctrine, but I'll take a shot in the dark. The end result you need to order by a function in mysql will need to be something like `ORDER BY FIELD(i.type,5,3,7)` So I'm guessing your line should be `$queryBuilder->orderBy("FIELD(i.type,5,3,7)");`

Comment: No, this is not passed by Doctrine parser (similar error like in the first case).